# How to Trigger a Scroll Behavior on a Toolbar inside a CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a `[PDFView][1]` as the direct child of a `CoordinatorLayout` as in:

[image]

I tried to add `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to the `PDFView` but it's not compatible so it isn't triggering any scroll behavior on the `Toolbar`.

The `Toolbar` has `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"` and I know it works because I already tested it with a `NestedScrollView` instead of the `PDFView`.

So I want to achieve this programatically, but I can't find any documentation on how to let the `CoordinatorLayout` know there's a scroll going on and it should animate the `Toolbar` going away.

How can I trigger this behavior programatically? The `PDFView` has a `ScrollListner` I just don't know how to connect it to the `CoordinatorLayout`.

Answer (score 1):

First the PDF view does not implement NestedScrollingChild2 , so you need to implement it. After implementing it , you have to implement [five](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/NestedScrollingChild2)
methods. Also create an instance [NestedScrollingChildHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/NestedScrollingChildHelper.html)  and delegate the implemented methods to this instance.

> View subclasses should instantiate a final instance of this class as a field at construction. For each View method that has a matching method signature in this class, delegate the operation to the helper instance in an overridden method implementation. This implements the standard framework policy for nested scrolling.

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Hmm it seems to be more work than I anticipated, I will add this to my "To Do" list, many thanks!

Comment: Do you know of any working examples or samples of this?

Comment: I tried the following code: https://gist.github.com/feinstein/8d2e0b87090d17a4135c365001a55106 but it doesn't work, I tried to implement `NestedScrollingChild2` and even `NestedScrollingChild` but only `stopNestedScroll()` is called, do you know why?